# Use a Select Statement for Variable Values

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables, table-functions

In SQL, I have a table function created which, in its definition, includes a variable called @customerid. Therefore, select statements need to include (@customerid).

When performing a select statement on the table function, I typically declare the variable value as shown below. However, this limits me to one customer. Whereas, I would like to return data on the table function for ALL customers.

```
DECLARE @customerid INT = 123456
SELECT * FROM custom.tfnCustomerRatings(@customerid)
```

I have attempted to set the value of the variable as a select statement. However, this throws an error as follows. Do I need to perform this differently? ***"Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression."***

```
DECLARE @customerid INT
SET @customerid = (SELECT distinct Customerid FROM compliance.CustomerTable WHERE CountryID = 1)
SELECT * FROM custom.tfnCustomerRatings(@customerid)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use cross apply... `select * from customertable c cross apply dbo.yourfunction(customerId) cf`

Comment: Thank you @siggemannen. Using cross apply worked. However it took 1 min to return results. However,the following runs in 4 seconds. SELECT * FROM  custom.tfnCustomerRatings(null)

WHERE CustomerID IN (SELECT DISTINCT CustomerID FROM Compliance.Customer WHERE CountryID = 1)

Comment: 'SELECT * FROM  custom.tfnCustomerRatings(null)

WHERE CustomerID IN (SELECT DISTINCT CustomerID FROM Compliance.Customer WHERE CountryID = 1)'

Comment: that's not the same query though. you don't select any customer data in the "fast" query, also, you need to add WHERE in the cross apply query

Comment: Also, performance wasn't part of your question, but fine, using table value functions might be slower, because for every customer row, it needs to get customer data one by one

Comment: Show your function definition. If there is a performance problem, it's there, and we can try to help fix it. The performance problem isn't because of `CROSS APPLY` (and I agree, your slow and fast queries are not the same - what exactly do you get back from the fast query?).

Answer (score 0):

Using cross apply returns results in 1 min. Using the below returns results in 4 seconds.

```
SELECT * FROM  custom.tfnCustomerRatings(null)
WHERE CustomerID IN (SELECT DISTINCT CustomerID FROM Compliance.Customer WHERE CountryID = 1)
```

Comment: Are you suggesting this is the solution? If not, then you should add the information to the question, not an answer. If this does solve your problem somehow, then mark it as accepted (but also remove the `DISTINCT`, it is extra work for no reason, especially if `Customer.CustomerID` is a key).